# What does resignFirstResponder mean?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In the login page, there are two text input (text1 and text2) to input username and password. After click login, it calls two `resignFirstResponder` on those two text boxs. I am wondering why need to call this method?

Comment: There is no method to resignFirstResponder on the current active textfield, so by calling it on both, the keyboard is guaranteed to disappear if either text field is active.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no idea what you are talking about, but resignFirstResponder will cause the textbox that currently has focus to release focus and the keyboard will hide.